# Is there a way to exclude a file mask from a BizTalk receive location?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-2013r2

I have a receivelocation in a folder where we pull all files, *.*

We are now going to receive .xslt on the same folder, and wish to pull those files with another receivelocation. Is there a way to exclude a specified file mask (*.xslt) from the original port?

Google tells me no, but the forum post was from 2007, so I figured it might be a way to do this in these modern times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

You will have to update your original receive location so that it does not wildcard pick up everything.  If you have more than one file mask that the port needs to pick up, then you will have to create a receive location on that same port for each of them.

And create a port with a receive location that only picks up *.xslt files.

Answer (score 0):

so far I cant find any `3rd party file adapter` to filter receive locations based on `filename` extension.

1 way to achieve this is using to `promote filename extension` and use it in your send port filter.

[image]